# MongoDB: Latest record for Each category by Timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to the MongoDb world. I have the following scenario:

A sales collection with following data:

```
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00.0Z"), "price" : 10, "quantity" : 20 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00.0Z"), "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00.0Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00.0Z"), "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00.0Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 6, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T12:05:10.0Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 7, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T14:12:12.0Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10 })
db.sales.insert({ "_id" : 8, "item" : "abc", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-10T08:00:00.0Z"), "price" : 10, "quantity" : 30 })
```

I want to select most recent sale (Whole Document) for each item.

Expected Result:

```
 [
  { "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "date" : "2014-02-03T09:00:00Z", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 },
  { "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "date" : "2014-02-15T08:00:00Z", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10 },
  { "_id" : 7, "item" : "xyz", "date" : "2014-02-15T14:12:12Z", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10 }
 ]
```

I've looked up for this but could't find a solution that can retrieve the most recent **whole document** for each category.

I've tried the following but I only get _id and lastSalesDate.

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { item: 1, date: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$item",
           lastSalesDate: { $last: "$date" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

How can I retrieve all the fields?

I'm using MongoDB driver and scala application where I need to retrieve the expected result. However, any solution in MongoDB query format is also welcome.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query,

```
db.sales.aggregate([ 

  // Sort by date (Use -1 to sort in descending order to get most recent date)
  { $sort: { date: -1 } }, 

  // Group by Item and Store First Sorted Whole Document in itemObj
  { $group: { _id: "$item", itemObj : { $first: "$$ROOT" }} }, 

  // Replace the Document with itemObj Object
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$itemObj"} }  
])
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammad , Thank you so much this gives the expected result. I'll try this out with MongoDb's scala driver.